# Valid B1/B2 "R" (regular) on expired diplomatic passport

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, passports, passport-renewals

Can I use my valid regular (non diplomatic) visa issued in my old and expired diplomatic passport with my new regular passport?